# Can Perl's Template Toolkit warn on undefined values?

Tags: perl, templates, warnings, template-toolkit

Is there a way to make Perl's `Template` display warnings for all undefined values that I attempt to use the [`GET` directive](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.20/lib/Template/Manual/Directives.pod#GET) on (via `[% %]`) during `Template::process`?

The default behavior is to ignore and move on. I'd like to warn *only* in the case of undefined values, if possible, and to log messages to STDERR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  If you pass the DEBUG option to `Template->new`, TT will warn you about undefined values.

See the docs here: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Variables.pod

Comment: Saw that, but was unsure whether it would spew a bunch of other stuff as well.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it go to a particular file handle?

Comment: Dunno, sorry :)  I use Template::Refine.

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for:

```
DEBUG_UNDEF
```

> This option causes the Template Toolkit to throw an 'undef' error whenever it encounters an undefined variable value.

```
use Template::Constants qw( :debug );

my $template = Template->new({
    DEBUG => DEBUG_UNDEF,
});
```

(From http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Config.pod.)

If you want to do some special handling of the exception, you'll need [to catch it or replace the `__DIE__` signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451227/how-can-i-get-around-a-die-call-in-a-perl-library-i-cant-modify/451236).

---

Let's put it together:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;
use Template::Constants qw( :debug );

my $debug_tt = Template->new({
   DEBUG => DEBUG_UNDEF,
});

my $tt = Template->new();

my $vars = {
    something => "42",
};

my $template = <<EOF;
First something undefined: [% nothing %].
And now something defined: [% something %].
EOF

my $output = '';

eval {$debug_tt->process(\$template, $vars, \$output)};
warn $debug_tt->error() if $debug_tt->error();

$tt->process(\$template, $vars);
```

The output is:

```
undef error - nothing is undefined
First something undefined: .
And now something defined: 42.
```

My approach was to use two different instances of the Template class:

1. `$debug_tt` which has the `DEBUG_UNDEF` flag turned on and hides its output in the `$output` variable.
2. `$tt` which is a vanilla instance and prints its output to `STDOUT` as is the default.

Both instances use the same template stored in `$template` and the same variable hash stored in `$vars`.  `$debug_tt` is wrapped in an `eval` to avoid exiting prematurely and a warning is emitted if `$debug_tt->error()` is true.  `$tt` is executed normally.  I think this satisfies your main requirements although it probably isn't efficient.  We need to parse `$template` twice using this method.

Some thoughts I had working on this:

1. It would have been nice if `Template::Toolkit` had used `Carp` so that we could get a bit more context on the warning.
2. One could probably derive a class from Template that would `warn` instead of `die` on error.  I didn't feel like doing that.
3. Depending on how your templates are set up, it might make sense to feed it in one line at a time so that you could emit line numbers when an undefined value is found.
4. It should be possible to alter the templates to test for their own errors and emit more sensible text in the face of undefined values.

Comment: Is there a way to have it *warn* on all undefined values but still render the template to completion?

Comment: Crap, I missed the deadline... sorry Jon, but thanks for the help!