# Toolkit Template to throw error when encounter undefined variable

Tags: template-toolkit

I am using Linux `tpage 2.7` (Template Toolkit version 2.27) with a bunch of template files. All variables are passed to `tpage` via command line as `--define var=value`. I would like `tpage` to throw some kind of error if variable exists in the template, but is not passed a definition via the command line. The `tpage --help` states the following in options:

```
--debug=STRING           Set TT DEBUG option to STRING
```

It is not clear what should be placed instead of `STRING`. I found a [manual](https://metacpan.org/release/ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.27/view/lib/Template/Manual/Config.pod#DEBUG) and for my version the debug flag is [DEBUG_UNDEF](https://metacpan.org/release/ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.27/view/lib/Template/Manual/Config.pod#DEBUG_UNDEF), but when I pass this option to `tpage` via command line like `--debug=DEBUG_UNDEF`, I get an error:

```
unknown debug flag: DEBUG_UNDEF
```

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571898/can-perls-template-toolkit-warn-on-undefined-values), but the answer does not provide a solution how to pass this switch option via the command line.

Q1: Is there any way to enable undefined exception via command line?

Q2: I want empty string like `--define myName=""` not to be considered as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the format option worked for me:

```
--debug="undef"
```