Warn instead of die (autowarn)
autodie

Replace functions with ones that succeed or die with lexical scope

I'm seeking for a solution which would warn instead of die like autodie does.
Is it possible without manually catching an exception, or checking return value of functions?

You might find some useful ideas in the answers to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451227/how-can-i-get-around-a-die-call-in-a-perl-library-i-cant-modify

Does Carp::Always cut it?  (If you can configure it to not die...)

Is it an option to overload die?

@zdim I guess preventing die() could work, although not sure whether distinction between regular die and autodie can be done.

I'm wondering what situations you think this would help that don't already give you a warning. For example, if an open fails and you do not handle it, a warning isn't helpful because the assumption about the state of the program ceases to be invalid (and you get the warning when you try to interact with the non-file handle). I never thought autodie was a good idea either, though.

@briandfoy close() dies on me and I would miss the information about it.

@mpapec: close($fh) or warn( "close failed: $!" ); I'd rather do that then come up with a tricky workaround that has spooky, implicit action at a distance.

@briandfoy tnx, I could take that route as a poor mans autowarn, and check rest of the code for similar candidates.
